# How to write the common.js style

Tags: javascript, commonjs

I have two functions

myFuncs.js

```
function funcA(e){
    console.log("FuncA:" + e);
}

function B(e){
     console.log("FuncB:" + e);
}
```

I would like to make common.js style module for these.

However I have some basic question.

I have read some articles and  try to understand standard method.

In this case,

I need to make two files separately for each function A and B?

Are these are correct??

in funcA.js

```
(function(definition){

    funcA = definition();
})(function(){//
    'use strict';

    var funcA = function funcA(e){};

    funcA.prototype = {
        console.log("funcA"+ e);
    }

    return funcA;
});
```

in main.js

```
var funcA = require("funcA.js");

funcA.funcA("test");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put them in one module with

```
// myFuncs.js
exports.funcA = function(e){
  console.log("FuncA:" + e);
}
// main.js
const myFuncs = require("./myFuncs")
myFuncs.funcA("test")
```

or export only one function

```
// funcA.js
module.exports = function(e){
  console.log("FuncA:" + e);
}
// main.js
const funcA = require("./funcA")
funcA("test");
```

You need a relative path, because `require("funcA")` will look in node_modules. And module names are usually lowercase and dash separated.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's the great guidance for me to common.js world. I start writing my own library.